# merge not working as expected: inner join not returning all matching rows from column 1

Tags: r, merge

I have two datasets, x and y, and I'm trying to match column one from x to column one of y but merge is not outputting the correct number of matches.

Example:

```
>x
species
Anisognathus_lacrymosus 
Anisognathus_notabilis 
Bangsia_melanochlamys 
Cnemathraupis_aureodorsalis
Catamenia_homochroa 
Chrysothlypis_salmoni 
Conirostrum_bicolor 
Conirostrum_rufum 

>y
species ln.mass
Acanthidops_bairdi  2.772588722
Anisognathus_igniventris    3.526360525
Anisognathus_lacrymosus 3.433987204
Anisognathus_melanogenys    3.713572067
Anisognathus_notabilis  3.663561646
Anisognathus_somptuosus 3.784189634
Bangsia_arcaei  3.616308761
```

output:

```
> merge(x,y)
[1] species ln.mass
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Desired output:

```
species ln.mass
Anisognathus_lacrymosus 3.433987204
Anisognathus_notabilis  3.663561646
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried with `match` and `dplyr` package and got the output.

```
x<- data.frame(species=c(
"Anisognathus_lacrymosus",
"Anisognathus_notabilis", 
"Bangsia_melanochlamys",
"Cnemathraupis_aureodorsalis",
"Catamenia_homochroa",
"Chrysothlypis_salmoni",
"Conirostrum_bicolor",
"Conirostrum_rufum" ))
y<-data.frame(species =c(
              "Acanthidops_bairdi",  
              "Anisognathus_igniventris",
              "Anisognathus_lacrymosus",
              "Anisognathus_melanogenys",    
              "Anisognathus_notabilis",
              "Anisognathus_somptuosus", 
              "Bangsia_arcaei"),
              ln.mass=c(2.772588722,3.526360525,3.433987204,3.713572067,3.663561646,3.784189634,3.616308761))

library(dplyr)
z<-y[match(x$species,y$species),]%>%na.omit()
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
                  species  ln.mass
3 Anisognathus_lacrymosus 3.433987
5  Anisognathus_notabilis 3.663562
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be joining on the species field.

```
merge(x,y, by="species")
```

Update : I did your same code and I got the output that you expected
[image]

Check for any whitespace in the text.

```
x$species <- gsub('\\s+', '', x$species)
y$species <- gsub('\\s+', '', y$species)
```

Comment: Are x and y both dataframes?

Comment: I got the output that you expected. Can you check if there are any whitespace at the start or end of the text?

Comment: Is there a way to keep y dataframe unsorted in the output?

Comment: Sort is true by default. You can make it unsorted by using `merge(x,y,sort=FALSE)`. Please accept the answer if you found it useful.